# Cheerio web scraping Twitter loading different data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, twitter

I'm new to Web Scraping, I'm using Axios to fetch the URL, and then access the data with Cheerio.

I want to web scrape twitter by getting my account's number of followers, I inspected the element who holds the number of followers, then tried to execute it, but it doesn't return anything

So I tried to execute each span tag in the page, and it returns the string "Something went wrong, but don’t fret — let’s give it another shot."

When I inspect the page, I can see the tag elements, but when I click on "view page source", it shows a totally different thing.

I found that the string "Something went wrong, but don’t fret — let’s give it another shot." is located in the page source here:

[image]

The element I want when inspecting my twitter page is:

[image]

This is my JS code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios')

axios('https://twitter.com/SaudAlghamdi97')
    .then(response => {

        run();

        async function run() {
            const html = await response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('span').each((i, el) => {
                console.log($(el).text());
            });
        }
    })
```

This is what I get in the terminal:

[image]

am I missing something here? I'm struggling to scrape the number of followers.

Comment: If you can't find them, they're being Javascript rendered and thus it's not possible with Cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

The data you request seems to be rendered by Javascript. You'll need another library for example [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), which will be able to view the rendered page like when you see it in your browser.

**"Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol"**